# A better way to do this htaccess rewrite rule

Tags: .htaccess, url-rewriting

I have this rewrite rule that checks for a country code in the url and fetches content accordingly.

Problem is there are 60+ countries. Can this be done in a different way rather than entering codes of all the countries in the rule?

```
RewriteRule ^/?(us|uk|ca)/p([0-9]+)/?$
```

Note the (us|uk|ca) part? A whole lot more need to go in there. Any better way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteRule ^/?([a-z][a-z])/p([0-9]+)/?$
```

But it doesn't check if the language is a valid one (and I don't know if you expect language codes with more than 2 characters if such a thing exists)

**EDIT :** this regexp is shorter :

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z]{2})/p\d+/?$
```

The first slash is useless and \d+ means one or more digits, see @TerryE's comment

Comment: The pattern is better written `^([a-z]{2}/p\d+/?$`.  Note that you won't see a leading slash in an `.htaccess` rewrite rule as the Perdir preprocessing strips this out.

Comment: Yeah, right, I just copy-pasted (sorry if it's the wrong expression, I'm french) and modified what thought was relevant, see the edit